# Pandas DataFrame: Compare Previous and Next Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am new to the the Python and Pandas, and have the following `DataFrame`:

```
predictedFeature   offset
        2000         1
        2000         2
        0            4
        0            6
        2200          9
        2200        11
        2200         15
        2200       16
        2200         17
         0            19
         0           21  
         0            22
         0           26
         200        29
         200         31
          0          35
         200         56
         200        59
         200       71
         200        73
         100       75
         100       77
         160       79
         160       80
         100       83
           0       87
         100       89
           0       91
```

I am trying to check the context of the value '0' in this column.  If a value is '0' I need to make an array of its previous three and next three values.

I already have an array which is like `required` `[100,162,200,262,156,160,256]`.

When I get ...

```
previous_array = [200,200,0]
next_array = [200,200,200]
```

... I need to check wether the `previous_array` has the values which are in my `required` array.

Can anyone help me with this, please?

for example,

I have the dataframe as I mentioned above.

Now , In this there are places where `0` is present. Now, I want to replace that 0 with the values from my required array. Now,

If we see I have a 0 at 3rd place in that dataframe. Now, If we take the previous 3 values then it will be only two as it self it is a third one.

so it will be [2000, 2000]
and next will be [0,2200,2200]

Now, If I check this arrays in the required array then these values are not present in it.So, I am not going to do anything with this.

Now If you see there is  0 in which previous three are,

```
[0,0,0] and next three are [200,200,0]
```

So Now If I compare this with required array and the next array gets matched with this then will replace that 0 with the `200`
So, likewise .

I have added the offset column as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use the [`pandas.DataFrame.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) function.

This function enables you to create a new column `pF_n` which is an offset (shift) of column `predictedFeature`, by shifting the values **up or down** by (n).  Then, you can loop over your rows using `df.iterrows()` to do a straight row compare to get prev/next third values from your zero row.  Then, build your array from those results.

#### For example:

```
import pandas as pd

vals = ['2000', '2000', '0', '0', '2200',
        '2200', '2200', '2200', '2200', '0',
        '0','0', '0', '200', '200', '0', '200',
        '200', '200', '200', '100', '100', '160',
         '160', '100', '0', '100', '0']

df = pd.DataFrame({'pF': vals})

# Shift to get the third **previous** value.
df['pF-3'] = df['pF'].shift(3)
# Shift to get the third **following** value.
df['pF3'] = df['pF'].shift(-3)

# Add values surrounding 0 to a list.
results = [row.values.tolist() for _, row in df.iterrows() if row['pF'] == 0]
```

#### Output:

```
      pF  pF-3   pF3
0   2000   NaN     0
1   2000   NaN  2200
2      0   NaN  2200
3      0  2000  2200
4   2200  2000  2200
5   2200     0  2200
6   2200     0     0
7   2200  2200     0
8   2200  2200     0
9      0  2200     0
10     0  2200   200
11     0  2200   200
12     0     0     0
13   200     0   200
14   200     0   200
15     0     0   200
...  ...   ...   ...
```

#### Array of values surrounding zero:

```
[[0.0, nan, 2200.0],
 [0.0, 2000.0, 2200.0],
 [0.0, 2200.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 2200.0, 200.0],
 [0.0, 2200.0, 200.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 200.0],
 [0.0, 160.0, nan],
 [0.0, 100.0, nan]]
```

With the `pF-3` column being three values previous, and the `pF3` column being the following third value.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to get these values in an array and then compare

Comment: @ganeshkaspate - Ok.  I've updated the code to add the values surrounding 0 to an array.  This should get you on the right track anyways.